# Filtering Prolog Rule Results

Tags: prolog

I have the Prolog rule:

```
superAbility(M1,A,M2) :-
    monsterAbility(M1,M1A),
    ability(M1A,M1T),
    monster(M2,M2T),
    typeEffectiveness(M1T,M2T,A).
```

Where `M1A` is Monster1 Ability, `M1T` is Monster1 Type and so on

I call the rule using: `superAbility(squirtle,A,charmander)`

and get the results

```
A = ordinary
A = super
A = super
A = ordinary
```

How do I alter my rule so that I only return when A = super?

Comment: Inside the rule you can rename `A` to `RequiredEffectiveness` and add the goal `RequiredEffectiveness = super` before the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices. First is to alter your function to get the result as mentioned from Isabelle Newbie:

```
superAbility(M1,A,M2) :-
    monsterAbility(M1,M1A),
    ability(M1A,M1T),
    monster(M2,M2T),
    A = super,
    typeEffectiveness(M1T,M2T,A).
```

Instead you can also call the predicate with the desired result:

```
?- superAbility(M1,super,M2).
```

Or you can use an additional predicate to tunnel the desired result:

```
superDuperAbility(M1,A,M2) :- 
    A = super,
    superAbility(M1,A,M2).
```

Or shorter without the unneccessary middle variable

```
superDuperAbility(M1,M2) :- superAbility(M1,super,M2).
```